# Dygraphs not using Data Labels

Tags: dygraphs

I've got a simple DyGraphs chart with three datasets. It's time based and everything is working except for data labels. I'm creating a CSV string with label headers and then passing it to the Dygraphs constructor like so:

```
var dataCSV ="Time,Avg,Max,Min\n";
// this next line runs in a loop a bunch of times
dataCSV += time + ',' + avg + ',' + max + ',' + min + '\n';

chart = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("chart"),
        dataCSV,
        {
            valueRange: [minVal*2,maxVal*2],
            xlabel: 'Acceleration (g)',
            labels: ['Time','Avg','Max','Min']
        }
);
```

(There's a lot more in the actual code but this is the general idea)

As you can see I'm also manually specifying the labels. It's still skipping over the first row in the CSV, ignoring the labels variable, and instead using the first numerical data row as the labels for some odd reason. Otherwise the data is displaying correctly with the proper time series and everything looks good. It's really bothering me because it should "just work" and I'm not getting any errors in the console.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: I created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/squaregoldfish/sL2p4c6m/  based on your code above that seems to work as you want it to. I think we'd need to see some real data to work out exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: Let me see if I can get a small chunk of the data and I'll update the OP

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, this was an error completely outside of DyGraph and 100% a PEBCAK. I was updating the code via SCP but putting the new files in an old working directory instead of the current site directory. Hence, none of the code changes were actually updating and I was left stumped as to why my changes weren't committing. Lesson learned - make sure you're uploading where you think you are.

Problem resolved!